# Document is not focused error when Document.hasFocus()

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have a simple piece of code that calls `await navigator.clipboard.writeText("Hi")`.

My issue is that, according to Sentry, it throws a "NotAllowedError: Document is not focused.".

Where I am confused is that according to logs just above it, `document.hasFocus()` returns True.
So the document *has* focus, but it is throwing a non-focus error?

Any ideas on how to fix this or where to log more?

Thanks in advance